# How do I reset an image, after being removed, using if assignment, in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

> With this function I am able to remove these two images from the webpage

```
function removeElement(){
    document.getElementById("imgbox1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.display = "none";
```

> And with this function I am able to reset the images, after I click on a button

```
function resetElement(Ali){
    document.getElementById("imgbox3").style.display = "block";
    
    if (Ali = "Mono"){
    document.getElementById("imgbox1").style.display = "block";
    }
    else if(Ali = "Tri"){
    document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

> With the code that I have I am able to reset the first image, however I which to be able to
> reset the second image using an if assignment. I am having trouble with the if's, because
> the code is only going through the first if.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, only one of the two if-blocks in resetElement() will ever be executed in a single call to the function, because Ali will either equal "Mono" or "Tri" (or maybe neither) but never both.

The only way to execute both would be to call the function twice with different arguments, eg:

```
resetElement("Mono");
resetElement("Tri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Man You put a single equal there ! do `==` or `===`
then this thing will definetly work by
`resetElement("Mono");` and
`resetElement("Tri);`